# Problem about 500 Internal Server Error in Python Flask

Tags: python, web, flask, internal-server-error

This is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/profile/<name>")

def profile(name):
  return render_template("index.html", name=name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

and HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        Hello {{ name }}
    </body>
</html>
```

And when I run the Python code, it shows on the browser that:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I looked for the solution on Google as well as Youtube, but still can't fix it. Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Edit: so all I need to do is to fix this one line:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")
```

Comment: Could you please switch to debug mode app.run(debug=True) to be able to give us more details ?

Comment: @Charles R now it says that "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html"

Comment: so your temple might not be in the right directory. By default template_forders="templates" with a plural S, you specified template without S

Answer (score 3):

Whenever we receive 500 internal server error on a Python wsgi application we can log it using 'logging'

First import `from logging import FileHandler,WARNING`

then after `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = 'template')`
add

```
file_handler = FileHandler('errorlog.txt')
file_handler.setLevel(WARNING)
```

Then you can run the application and when you receive a 500 Internal server error, cat/nano your `errorlog.txt` file to read it, which will show you what the error was caused by.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must not had an empty line beetween
   `@app.route("/profile/<name>")` and `def profile(name):`
2. You have to set the html file in a folder called templates.
3. You have to set the templates folder and run.py in the same folder

Comment: I followed everything you said, yet it's still not working, the browser keep saying that "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: I have the same.  All of sudden when I woke up this morning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below by adding the type string in your @app.route :

```
@app.route("/profile/<string:name>")
def profile(name):
  return render_template("test.html", name=name)
```