# flask 500 Errror

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/bg",methods = ['POST'])
@cross_origin()

def bg():
    
    get_json = request.get_json()
    
    base64image =get_json["image"]
    base64image =  base64image.split(',' , 1)
    input = base64.b64decode(base64image[1])

    output =  remove(input)

    binaryImage =  base64.b64encode(output)
    binaryImage =  binaryImage.decode('utf-8')
    binaryImage =  base64image[0]+","+binaryImage

    return  {"image":binaryImage},200
```

this code working on local but not on production (500 internal server error)

please solve it!!

Comment: try this link, i think it may help you: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655167/problem-about-500-internal-server-error-in-python-flask)

Comment: post the complete error log from prod, need to see where the error is coming from. error code 500 is very broad to understand what is going on!

Comment: Error 500 means something is wrong with your back end code, you have to send the full error for us to see what is wrong.

Comment: Please share error message

Comment: Full Error @walker
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: No the error from your python console not the html page.